# Getting Supabase Edge Function's bundled script

Tags: telegram-bot, supabase

I am using Supabase's Edge Function to create a simple telegram bot (based on Webhook's). When I am deploying the function to Supabase and then invoking it through Telegram, I am getting the following error message in the log:
[image: Error]

How can I go about debugging this error? Can I get the bundled source code of the edge function so that I can make changes to my script to correct the same?

Comment: Where are you getting this log?

Comment: I opened my edge function on supabase site, and then went to the logs section there.

Comment: Can you try upgrading the Supabase CLI to the latest version and redeploying your function. We've changed the way functions are bundled and deployed which should fix this.